# Can not find kernel boot sector and kernel setup from /dev/mem on RHEL 7.4

Tags: kernel

In RHEL 6 I dump `/dev/mem` to `file1` using `dd`. According to kernel boot protocol, I can find the kernel boot sector and kernel setup in `file1`; the two parts are the same as `vmlinuz`.

But in RHEL 7.4 using the same methold I can not find the kernel boot sector and kernel setup. Why?

Comment: even i use crash command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we use comments only for clarification requests or for responging on that requests. Otherwise, instead of commenting **your own question post**, add corresponding information to the post itself via [edit]ing it.